# iOS: Drawing a Bounding Box Around Non Transparent Pixels In Image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics, cgrect

Say I have an image with a transparent background such as the following:

[image]

How can I get the bounding rect for each object and not just one big one?

[image]

I'm currently using this [category](https://github.com/wrep/UIImage-Trim) to trim the whitespace out. But I'm not sure how to make it separate objects from each other so they each have their own bounding box, or set a minimum threshold so it doesn't pick up anything smaller than say 16x16 if it's by itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem in computer vision called [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). The algorithm is not difficult to implement yourself. There are also third-party implementations out there like [this (Swift)](https://github.com/nfergu/cclabel), and [this (Objective-C)](https://github.com/agnivsen/ConnectedComponents), and OpenCV definitely has [this feature available](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html).